# Is this condition of qobject_cast intended to returns only true?

Tags: c++, qt

I have already read about qobject_cast and related questions.
I'm new to C++.

This is the same thing as dynamic_cast but this is for only Qt, subclasses of QObject.

I often run into the casts are used for if statement.

For example,

```
if (const QStyleOptionButton *button = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionButton *>(option))
```

or,

```
if (qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(widget)
        || qobject_cast<QRadioButton *>(widget)
        || qobject_cast<QSlider *>(widget)) {
        widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
    }
```

### This is qstyleoption_cast

```
template <typename T>
T qstyleoption_cast(const QStyleOption *opt)
{
    typedef typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type Opt;
    if (opt && opt->version >= Opt::Version && (opt->type == Opt::Type
        || int(Opt::Type) == QStyleOption::SO_Default
        || (int(Opt::Type) == QStyleOption::SO_Complex
            && opt->type > QStyleOption::SO_Complex)))
        return static_cast<T>(opt);
    return nullptr;
}
```

### This is qobject_cast

```
template <class T>
inline T qobject_cast(QObject *object)
{
    typedef typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type ObjType;
    Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(QtPrivate::HasQ_OBJECT_Macro<ObjType>::Value,
                    "qobject_cast requires the type to have a Q_OBJECT macro");
    return static_cast<T>(ObjType::staticMetaObject.cast(object));
}
template <class T>
inline T qobject_cast(const QObject *object)
{
    typedef typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type ObjType;
    Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(QtPrivate::HasQ_OBJECT_Macro<ObjType>::Value,
                      "qobject_cast requires the type to have a Q_OBJECT macro");
    return static_cast<T>(ObjType::staticMetaObject.cast(object));
```

---

In the case of qstyleoption_cast, this returns nullptr unless the condition is filled, it means false.

On the other hand, in the case of qobject_cast, this occurs compile error because of static_cast when it fails.

That is to say, the latter example code,

```
if (qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(widget)
        || qobject_cast<QRadioButton *>(widget)
        || qobject_cast<QSlider *>(widget)) {
        widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
    }
```

Is this intended to return true absolutely? When it fails, this will occur compile error.
That is to say, is this only intended to prevent bugs?

I think this doesn't make sense because widget is a subclass of `QObject`. But in the case of our own subclasses of widget, there is the possibility that the subclass has no `Q_OBJECT` macro, so this codes want to check it.

---

Comment: the `qobject_cast` can still return `nullptr` if the input pointer is already `nullptr`

Comment: `qobject_cast` only fails with static assert when you are trying to cast to some type that does not in fact derive from `QObject` or doesn't have `Q_OBJECT` macro in the class definition. If the class does derive from `QObject`, but is not in the inheritance hierarchy of `object` argument, then `qobject_cast` returns nullptr. Thus, `qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(widget)` will happily compile, and will return `nullptr` if at run time it turns out that `widget` is of a type other than `QPushButton` or a class derived from `QPushButton`

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I think qobject_cast returns the result of static_cast. I heard that static_cast occurs compile error if it fails, so we cannot fail in the if statement. I have judged that this if statement is for checking the compile error.

Comment: `ObjType::staticMetaObject.cast(object)` is where the real work happens, where the metadata is consulted and run-time type of the object is checked. This call returns `nullptr` if the types do not match, or `QObject*` pointer if they do. `static_cast` then simply coerces the returned `QObject*` pointer (possibly null) to the requested type.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Yes, if ObjType::staticMetaObject.cast(object) fails, what becomes? This cannot fail at all? If so, the if statement doesn't make sense of checking them, or this is for checking compile error.

Comment: If `object` doesn't in fact have `ObjType` in its inheritance hierarchy, then `ObjType::staticMetaObject.cast(object)` returns `nullptr`. `static_cast<Anything*>(nullptr) == nullptr`. If `object` does have `ObjType` in its inheritance hierarchy, then that call returns `object` back unchanged. `static_cast<SomeTypeDerivedFromQObject*>(object)` is a valid cast. I'm afraid I don't know how to explain this any clearer.

Comment: @Igor Tandtnik I grasped it!